# How to add new column before first column in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I need to add a column at first in Sql using laravel migration. i can add new column at any place using after:

```
  Schema::table('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        if (Schema::hasColumn('tasks', 'assigned_to_id') == false) {
                $table->integer('assigned_to_id')->after('status');
        }
  });
```

Table has following fields:
 project_id , module_id

I need to add column 'id' before project_id.
How to achieve this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try and see if using [after()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations) 2 times does the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `$table->integer('id')->first()` to add `id` as the first column

Comment: Thank You @Hasta Dhana !